# IndexError: index 261861 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 169567

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, error-handling, vcf-vcard

I am a beginner in programming and I have the following problem:
I want to write a definition where I create an empty matrix with the data of the chosen chromosome out of a vcf-file (with pyvcf).The empty matrix is created correctly.

IndexError: index 261861 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 169567

But this error above occurs if I try the second chromosome as input. The first chromosome ends at index 262860, this is why I think somehow it want to place the data of the line in this line of the matrix, but I do not understand why!

This is my code:

```
def creatematrix(newfile):

'''Based on the choice of a chromosome, this function fetches the positions and the DP values out of the vcf and saves it in a matrix.'''

    vcf_reader = vcf.Reader(open(newfile), 'r')
    numpos=0
    Chr=input("Chromosome: ")
    with open(newfile,'r') as newerfile: 
        for line in newerfile: 
            if line.startswith(Chr):
                numpos=numpos+1

    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(numpos,6)) -> here i am creating the matrix with so much lines as lines are in the vcf for the chosen chromosome (numpos)

    z=0
    for rec in vcf_reader:
        if rec.CHROM==Chr:
            matrix[z,0]=rec.CHROM
            matrix[z,1]=rec.POS 
            for samples in rec.samples:
                matrix[z,2]=samples['GT']
                matrix[z,3]=samples['DP']
        z=z+1
```

I really hope that someone could help me with this!

Greetings,
Milena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding up z for every line in vcf_reader, while you only want to do that if the chromosome you want is identified.

Simply putting z=z+1 inside the if statement should do the trick like so:

```
z=0
for rec in vcf_reader:
    if rec.CHROM==Chr:
        matrix[z,0]=rec.CHROM
        matrix[z,1]=rec.POS 
        for samples in rec.samples:   # You might want to check this for loop as well. Now you are overwriting matrix[z, 2] and matrix[z, 3] everytime so you only save the last samples?
            matrix[z,2]=samples['GT']
            matrix[z,3]=samples['DP']
        z=z+1 # z now only increases when the matched chromosome is found.
```

Comment: Case closed! Thank you so much.